# How to disable/enable specific EventTrigger in unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a 5 EventTrigger that i have attached to an Image. There are

"begin drag", "drag", "end drag", "pointer enter". "pointer exit"

 
like this image

[image]

I am able to disable all of them at once with

```
eventTrigger.enabled = false;
```

However what i would like to achieve is to just disable the "begin Drag" event.

Does anyone know how to do it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put a flag in `UIDragableScript` instead.

```
public bool allowBeginDrag;
```

Set the boolean.

```
indicatorWidgetObject.GetComponent<UIDragableScript>().allowBeginDrag = false;
```

Then, make `UIdragableScript.BeginDrag` depend on it.

```
UIdragableScript.BeginDrag()
{
    if(!allowBeginDrag) return;

    // ...
}
```

---

You might want to consider using the [`IDragXHandler`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/EventSystems.IDragHandler.html) and [`IPointerXHandler`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/EventSystems.IPointerEnterHandler.html) interfaces instead of the `EventTrigger` to implement the logic into the scripts themselves:

**UIDragableScript**

```
public class UIDragableScript : MonoBehaviour, IBeginDragHandler, IDragHandler, IEndDragHandler
{
    public bool allowBeginDrag;

    public void OnBeginDrag(PointerEventData eventData)
    {
        if(!allowBeginDrag) return;

        // ...
    }

    public void OnDrag(PointerEventData eventData)
    {
        // ...
    }

    public void OnEndDrag(PointerEventData eventData)
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```

**UIHoverScript**

```
public class UIHoverScript : MonoBehaviour, IPointerEnterHandler, IPointerExitHandler
{
    public void OnPointerEnter(PointerEventData pointerEventData)
    {
        // ...
    }

    //Detect when Cursor leaves the GameObject
    public void OnPointerExit(PointerEventData pointerEventData)
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```

> Ensure an `EventSystem` exists in the Scene to allow click/hover/etc detection. For click/hover/etc detection on non-UI GameObjects, ensure a `PhysicsRaycaster` is attached to the `Camera`. (from [IPointerClickHandler](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/EventSystems.IPointerClickHandler.html))

And then, don't use the `EventTrigger` at all.

Comment: it workss!!. thank you very much for your suggestions!（＾ｖ＾）